# Hamming distance in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to find a faster way to calculate Hamming distance between two numpy arrays. The arrays can be assumed to be of size A(N1 x D) and B(N2 x D)

My working attempt so far:

```
result = np.zeros((A.shape[0], B.shape[0]))
for i in range(A.shape[0]):
    for j in range(B.shape[0]):
        result[i, j] = np.sum(A[i, :] != B[j, :]) #resulting array is of size (1 x D)
return result
```

This is not fast enough tho. I tried to use `numpy.count_nonzero` rather than `sum`, but it raises the following exception:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all().
```

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention, the arrays only contain 1 and 0 values, if that changes anything

My question is: is it possible to make it work?
As a bonus question: why `numpy.count_nonzero` passes an array to `__bool()__` in my code, rather than one particular value?

Comment: sklearn has a fast implementation in [`sklearn.neighbors.DistanceMetric`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.DistanceMetric.html)

Comment: Try `np.count_nonzero(A[:, None, :] != B, axis=2)`

Comment: @PaulPanzer `IndexError: invalid number of indices`. I'm quite new to Python, how should I use this? (I simply tried to print the result).

Comment: When exactly does the error occur? Also, could you double check `A.shape` and `B.shape` are (`N1, D)` and `(N2, D)`?

Comment: Ooops. Apparently, the arguments passed to function were csr sparse matrices, not numpy arrays. That was my problem. After creating numpy arrays with `A=A.toarray()` it works several times faster (and `numpy.count_nonzero()` also works correctly). I suppose question should be deleted (I can't think of a way to edit it, since the problem was in completely different area than my question).

Answer (score 1):

You can implement this your way, using NumPy broadcasting, or using scikit learn. **SciKit learn is the fastest**.

```
import numpy as np
import sklearn.neighbors as sn

N1 = 345
N2 = 3450
D = 128

A = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(N1, D))
B = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(N2, D))

def slow(A, B):
    result = np.zeros((A.shape[0], B.shape[0]))
    for i in range(A.shape[0]):
        for j in range(B.shape[0]):
            result[i, j] = np.sum(A[i, :] != B[j, :]) #resulting array is of size (1 x D)
    return result

def fast(A, B):
    return np.count_nonzero(A[:, None, :] != B[None, :, :], axis=-1)

def sklearn(A, B):
    return sn.DistanceMetric.get_metric("hamming").pairwise(A, B) * A.shape[-1]

%timeit -r1 -n1 slow(A, B)
# 7.86 s ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)
%timeit -r1 -n1 fast(A, B)
# 335 ms ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)
%timeit -r1 -n1 sklearn(A, B)
# 51.1 ms ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)

np.allclose(slow(A, B), fast(A, B))  # True
np.allclose(fast(A, B), sklearn(A, B))  # True
```

Answer (score 0):

based on what @Paul suggested, I compared time consumption for the two methods given big size `numpy.ndarray`:

```
import numpy as np
import time

def binarize(FV):
    return np.where(FV > 0, 1, 0).astype(int)

def hammingDist():
    a, b = -1, 1
    u = (b - a) * np.random.random_sample((3450, 128)) + a
    v = (b - a) * np.random.random_sample((3450, 128)) + a

    b_t = time.time()
    b_u, b_v = binarize(u), binarize(v)
    print('binarization time : {} s'.format(time.time()-b_t))

    h_slow_t = time.time()
    H = np.zeros((b_v.shape[0], b_u.shape[0]))
    for i in range(b_v.shape[0]):
        for j in range(b_u.shape[0]):
            H[i, j] = np.sum(b_v[i, :] != b_u[j, :])
    print('H =\n{}'.format(H))
    print('t: {} s'.format(time.time()-h_slow_t))

    h_f = time.time()
    H_fast = np.count_nonzero(b_v[:, None, :] != b_u, axis=2)
    print('H_fast =\n{}'.format(H_fast))
    print('t: {} s'.format(time.time()-h_f))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    hammingDist()
```

the result:

```
binarization time : 0.010922908783 s
H =
[[60. 75. 65. ... 66. 56. 66.]
 [64. 57. 69. ... 78. 64. 58.]
 [62. 63. 65. ... 60. 66. 68.]
 ...
 [60. 63. 69. ... 66. 60. 64.]
 [68. 59. 59. ... 52. 62. 74.]
 [75. 70. 58. ... 59. 65. 65.]]
t: 53.5885431767 s
H_fast =
[[60 75 65 ... 66 56 66]
 [64 57 69 ... 78 64 58]
 [62 63 65 ... 60 66 68]
 ...
 [60 63 69 ... 66 60 64]
 [68 59 59 ... 52 62 74]
 [75 70 58 ... 59 65 65]]
t: 2.6171131134 s
```

Comment: Your answer has **so much needless code**, it is practically impossible to find what is important here...